# Find $c$ and $n$ such that $\frac{x^3 \arctan x}{x^4 + \cos x +3} \sim cx^n$ as $x \to 0$

Tags: limits, functions

Where is my mistake in the below:

$$\frac{1}{c} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^3 \arctan x}{x^{4+n} + x^n \cos x + 3x^n} = \frac{1}{c} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^4}{x^{4+n}+x^n \cos x + 3x^n} \\ =\frac{1}{c} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^n + x^{n-4} \cos x + 3x^{n-4}}$$

Looking at it now it feels like it is the step that I am about to do, because it appears as though the denominator becomes smaller and smaller going to infinity. However, my reasoning was that since it is given that there can be an equivalence between $cx^n$ and our function, i.e. the limit is finite and goes to $1$ as $x \to 0$, then it also must be true that if we invert the fraction, then the limit is still finite and is $1/1=1$ as $x \to 0$. So, next step:

$$c \lim_{x \to 0} \left(x^n + x^{n-4}\cos x + 3x^{n-4} \right)$$

$$c \lim_{x \to 0} (x^{n-4}(\cos x -1))=1$$
$$-c \lim_{x \to 0} \left(x^{n-4} \frac{x^2}{2}\right) = 1$$

We need $x^{n-4} = x^{-2}$ $\implies n=2$

$$-c \frac{1}{2} =1 \implies c=-2$$

Comment: True. But where have I made a mistake though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$\frac{x^3 \arctan x}{x^4 + \cos x +3}\sim\frac{x^4}{x^4+4}\sim \frac14 x^4$$

and the guess is correct indeed

$$\frac{\frac{x^3 \arctan x}{x^4 + \cos x +3}}{\frac14 x^4}\to 1$$

As an alternative

$$\frac{\frac{x^3 \arctan x}{x^4 + \cos x +3}}{c x^n}=\frac1c\frac{x^3 \arctan x}{x^{4+n} + x^n\cos x +3x^n}=\frac1c\frac{x^4 +o(x^4)}{x^{4+n} + x^n+o(x^{n}) +3x^n}=$$$$=\frac1c\frac{1 +o(1)}{4x^{n-4}+o(x^{n-4})} \to 1$$

from which we obtain $n=4$ and $c=\frac14$.

Comment: how did you rewrite the denominator like that?

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal the $x^4$ term at the denominator is negligible with respect to 4

Comment: I still do not understand how you went from $x^4+\cos x + 3$ to $x^4 + 4$

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal We have that $\cos x\sim 1$.

Comment: But if $f_1 \sim g_1$ and $f_2 \sim g_2$, then $f_1 \pm f_2 \nsim g_1 \pm g_2$

Comment: Is this case an exception to the above rule?

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal You are right,  note that in the first part we don't need to be completely rigorous, in that way we can guess what the result is. Then we can prove that rigoursly by the limit.

Comment: I see. Thanks for helping me out. But I would also be thankful if you could point me to the error that I have made in my calculations, so that I do not repeat the mistake in the future.

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal It is a way to simplify the derivation. A first not completely rigorous guess and then a rigorous proof. Of course we can also proceed in other ways.

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal I add a solution carried out with your method.

Comment: Solved the case for $x \to \infty$ in my head :) And the instructor's solution to the above problem was almost like yours, he rewrote the whole denominator like so: $x^4 + \cos x +3 \sim 4$, just like you, but without the intermediate step.

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal Ah ok, sorry I didn't recognize your confusion! Bye

Answer (score 1):

It should be obvious that $c\neq 0$ otherwise the definition of $\sim$ is in trouble. Next we can note that the given condition implies $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{cx^n(3+\cos x+x^4)}{x^3\arctan x} =1$$ Using the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} (1/x)\arctan x=1$ we can see that the above condition is equivalent to $$4c\lim_{x\to 0}x^{n-4}=1$$ Now it should be obvious that $n=4$ as $n<4$ makes the limit infinite and $n>4$ makes the limit $0$ and then $c=1/4$.

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you